# Flutter navigation how to move to the second page for each item

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have navigation in my main.dart

```
class Homescreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _Home createState() => _Home();
}

class _Home extends State<Homescreen> {
 double xOffset = 0;
 double yOffset = 0;
 double scaleFactor = 1;

 bool isDrawerOpen = false;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return AnimatedContainer(
 transform: Matrix4.translationValues(xOffset, yOffset, 0)
    ..scale(scaleFactor),
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
  color: Colors.grey[200],
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
     

        //  Main homescreen view
        Container(
          height: 120,
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: categories.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              boxShadow: shadowList,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              categories[index]['iconPath'],
                              height: 50,
                              width: 50,
                            ),
                            onTap: () {

                                Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Names()),
                                );
                            },
                          )),
                      Text(categories[index]['name']),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),

        );
       }
      }
```

Below is my configuration.dart file which has the menu items and icons

```
  Color primaryGreen = Color(0xff416d6d);
  List<BoxShadow> shadowList = [
    BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 30, offset: Offset(0, 10))
  ];

   List<Map> categories = [
   {'name': 'Prayer times', 'iconPath': 'images/prayer.jpg'},
   {'name': 'Nearby Mosque', 'iconPath': 'images/nearby.jpg'},
   {'name': 'Zakar Calculator', 'iconPath': 'images/calculator.png'},
   {'name': 'Islamic Calender', 'iconPath': 'images/islamic.png'},
   {'name': 'Tasbeh', 'iconPath': 'images/tasbeh.png'}
 ];
```

I added below functionality to move the page to the next page but in a single page it working but I want to move for all the pages so, how would I configure my below code to move on to the each different pages.

```
                        onTap: () {

                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Names()),
                            );
                        },
                      )),
```

Answer (score 0):

I got that by adding the following code in the top of the page

```
      @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
         return MaterialApp(
         home: Homescreen2(),
         initialRoute: '/home',
         routes: {
         //first route
           categories[0]['route']: (context) => PrayTimes(),
           categories[1]['route']: (context) => Nearby(),
           categories[2]['route']: (context) => Quran(),
           categories[3]['route']: (context) => Qibla(),
           categories[4]['route']: (context) => Six(),
           categories[5]['route']: (context) => Pop(),
           categories[6]['route']: (context) => Names(),
           categories[7]['route']: (context) => NamesM(),
           categories[8]['route']: (context) => Live(),
           categories[9]['route']: (context) => Naats(),
           categories[10]['route']: (context) => Cards(),
           categories[11]['route']: (context) => Duaa(),
           categories[12]['route']: (context) => Zakat(),
           categories[13]['route']: (context) => Community(),
           // Text(categories[0]['name']),// second route
     },
   );
  }
}
```